# how to manipulate user submitted text and display it with django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, form-submit

I want to build a very simple webapp that takes a user's text, runs a function on it that alters it and then displays the altered text. I have the code for the function but everything else is unclear.

I am very new to django and just need a push in the right direction with this problem. At the very least, tell me what to google, I've went through several tutorials but neither of them dealt with this kind of task.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do that in javascript, no need for django.

Comment: Maybe the online django book? http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html it very quickly gets to this sort of thing.

Comment: Validation is better to be run in both server side and client side , but for your problem i think as @dietbacon it is better to use java script.

Comment: Look up jQuery, it should be very straightforward to do what you want using it. If you must absolutely do this server side, you should send an AJAX request to the server with the text if you wanna stay on the same page, or send a POST request to the server with this data (using a form on the html) that calls on the other view you wish to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define a form; in forms.py under your app's folder

   ```
   class MyForm(forms.Form):
       myinput = forms.forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   ```
2. Define a function in your views.py

   ```
   import .forms
   def handle_form(request):
       if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
           form = MyForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
           if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
               # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
               # ...
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
       else:
           form = MyForm() # An unbound form

       return render(request, 'handle_form.html', {
           'form': form,
       })
   ```
3. Add a template

   ```
       <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       </form>
   ```

Of course you need to add it to your urls.py
Most info was copy pasted from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/

Comment: thanks @acidjunk! I figured forms might do the trick but I currently don't have the knowledge to use them properly. I will definitely try to use this.

Comment: U R Welcome. When you want to use Django for it; it's probably better to define a database table and store your the value entered in the form there. Then write a second view where you call your function. Another option would be to save the form post to a session variabele; and write a view that calls your function.

The tutorial on django will learn you how to do it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: hey, it only took me 7 months :) sorry about the delay, I didn't know what I was supposed to do and I've just logged in for the second time.